# Why Alt+Tab dose not open tasks switcher?

Tags: kubuntu

After installing fresh Kubuntu 22.04

I found that Alt+Tab dose not open tasks switcher in any way

I have these
https://prnt.sc/Lmu7Jndvp8BP

options set and these :
https://prnt.sc/D1hM2K3r0QI4

Not sure, looks like I ocasionanally changed some option  I did not have to change...
Any hints?

Comment: Where can I check/change Hot keys for this option ?
I search in System Settings/Shortcuts- did not find something similar... I suppose it must be called 
something like “Tasks switcher”...

I tried to use other keyboard and it works ok - so thta is problem in my OS...